# How to convert one json format to another using python module

Tags: python, json

How to convert one json format to another json using python module. 
I have one json object. Want to take the keys and values. How to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Input json:

```
{
    "A": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "object",
    "value": {
      "X": "some value1",
      "Y": "some value2"
    }
  },
  "B": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "object",
    "value": [
      "1": "some value1",
      "2": "some value2"
    ]
  },
  "C": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "object",
    "value": {
      "ABC": "some value1",
      "XYZ": "some value2"
    }
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "A": {
        "value": {
            "X": "some value1",
            "Y": "some value2"
        }
    },
    "B": {
        "value": [
            "1": "some value1",
            "2": "some value2"
        ]
    },
    "C": {
        "value": {
            "ABC": "some value1",
            "XYZ": "some value2"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither of these is JSON. Typos aside, where are you at? Are you able to load the data into a Python object? Do you know how to delete a key from a dictionary?

Comment: Have you tried any thing so far, it looks like simple formatting.

Comment: I am new to python, could you please help me with the way @Sushanth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a dict comprehension which is less destructive than deleting keys:

```
{k:{'value': v['value']} for k, v in data.items()}
```

P.S: your example data is corrupt and throws errors in Python please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your json-dict and delete particular keys

```
for key in json_object:
  del json_object[key]["sensitive"]
  del json_object[key]["type"]
```